# using nokogiri to parse google picasa api xml - namespacing issue?

Tags: xml, google-api, nokogiri

I am trying to get some data from some google picasa xml, and am having a bit of trouble..

Here is the actual xml (containing just one entry):
http://pastie.org/1736008

Basically, I would like to collect a few of the gphoto attributes, so ideally what I would like to do is:

```
doc.xpath('//entry').map do |entry|
  {:id => entry.children['gphoto:id'],
   :thumb => entry.children['gphoto:thumbnail'],
   :name => entry.children['gphoto:name'],
   :count => entry.children['gphoto:numphotos']}
end
```

However, this does not work...  In fact, when I examine the children of entry, I do not even see any 'gphoto:xxx' atttributes at all...  So I am quite confused as to how to find them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some working code which uses nokogiri to extract the gphoto elements from your example xml.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
content = File.read('input.xml')
doc = Nokogiri::XML(content) {|config| 
          config.options = Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::STRICT
      }

hashes = doc.xpath('//xmlns:entry').map do |entry|
  {
    :id => entry.xpath('gphoto:id').inner_text,
    :thumb => entry.parent.xpath('gphoto:thumbnail').inner_text,
    :name => entry.xpath('gphoto:name').inner_text,
    :count => entry.xpath('gphoto:numphotos').inner_text
  }
end

puts hashes.inspect

# yields: 
#
# [{:count=>"37", :name=>"Melody19Months", :thumb=>"http://lh3.ggpht.com/_Viv8WkAChHU/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAAAAAAAAAA/pNuu5PgnP1Y/s64-c/soopingsaw.jpg", :id=>"5582695833628950881"}]
```

Notes:

1. The sample xml in your gist needed a closing "feed" tag.  Fixed [here](http://pastie.org/1736460).
2. In the xpath expression to find the entry elements we must use a namespace prefix, so   "xmlns:entry", not just "entry".  The latter (used in your original code) will find **no** elements.  It is looking for elements in the null namespace, but in your example, they all inherit the default namespace specified on the feed element.  Aaron Patterson wrote a (Nokogiri-centric) introduction to the problem, [here](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/04/23/namespaces-in-xml/), and there's another [here](http://www.edankert.com/defaultnamespaces.html).
3. The element gphoto:thumbnail is a child of the *feed* element, and **not** of each entry.  I have made a small (hacky) adjustment for that, keeping in the design of your original example, but it would be *far* better to seek out the value of this element only once per feed (perhaps later populating the entry hashes if they really need to each keep a copy).
4. Configuring Nokogiri to be strict is not actually necessary, but it's nice to get a little help in spotting problems early.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the `entry` nodes, then look inside each one to extract the `gphoto` namespaced nodes:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('./test.xml'))
hashes = doc.search('//xmlns:entry').map do |entry|
  h = {}
  entry.search("*[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007']").each do |gphoto|
    h[gphoto.name] = gphoto.text
  end
  h
end

require 'ap'
ap hashes
# >> [
# >>     [0] {
# >>                        "id" => "5582695833628950881",
# >>                      "name" => "Melody19Months",
# >>                  "location" => "",
# >>                    "access" => "public",
# >>                 "timestamp" => "1299649559000",
# >>                 "numphotos" => "37",
# >>                      "user" => "soopingsaw",
# >>                  "nickname" => "sooping",
# >>         "commentingEnabled" => "true",
# >>              "commentCount" => "0"
# >>     }
# >> ]
```

That returns all the `//entry/gphoto:*` notes. If you want only certain ones you can filter for what you want:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('./test.xml'))
hashes = doc.search('//xmlns:entry').map do |entry|
  h = {}
  entry.search("*[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007']").each do |gphoto|
    h[gphoto.name] = gphoto.text if (%w[id thumbnail name numphotos].include?(gphoto.name))
  end
  h
end

require 'ap'
ap hashes

# >> [
# >>     [0] {
# >>                "id" => "5582695833628950881",
# >>              "name" => "Melody19Months",
# >>         "numphotos" => "37"
# >>     }
# >> ]
```

Notice that in the original question an attempt to access `gphoto:thumbnail` occurs, however there is no matching node for `//element/gphoto:thumbnails`, so it can't be found.

Another way to write the search using the namespace is:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('./test.xml'))
hashes = doc.search('//xmlns:entry').map do |entry|
  h = {}
  entry.search("*").each do |gphoto|
    h[gphoto.name] = gphoto.text if (
      (gphoto.namespace.prefix=='gphoto') && 
      (%w[id thumbnail name numphotos].include?(gphoto.name))
    )
  end
  h
end

require 'ap'
ap hashes

# >> [
# >>     [0] {
# >>                "id" => "5582695833628950881",
# >>              "name" => "Melody19Months",
# >>         "numphotos" => "37"
# >>     }
# >> ]
```

Rather than using XPath, it's asking Nokogiri to look at each node's namespace attributes.